# not getting location using gps in android

Tags: android, gps

I'm trying sample code for getting location using gps service.bt not gettong location.
Below is my code.-

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{

    Location mLocation;
    LocationManager mManager;
    LocationListener mlistener;
    Geocoder mcoder;
    Context context;
    TextView txtLat;
    String lat;
    String provider;
    protected String latitude,longitude; 
    protected boolean gps_enabled,network_enabled;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    }

    public void getMyLocation(){

            String addressString = "";

        final Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

        try
        {
            final List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(18.5203, 73.8567, 4);
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            System.out.println("location..."+sb);
            if ( addresses.size() > 0 )
            {
                final Address address = addresses.get(0);
                for ( int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++ )
                {
                    sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                }
                sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
                sb.append(address.getCountryName());
            }
            addressString = sb.toString();
        }
        catch ( final IOException e )
        {
        }

    txtLat.setText("Your Current Position is:\n" +
             "\n" + addressString);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    getMyLocation();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 }
```

Comment: What is the output? ie, what's on TextView?

Comment: just showing Your Current Position is:

Comment: Consider to put a LOG inside 'if' condition in `getMyLocation()`. This ensures the method is called and the address is retrieved. Also check if `addresses.size()` is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your code just needs some minor changes.

- You must implement all methods of the listener to understand if the provider is available, if any is built into the device and if you can expect Location updates anyway.
- In `getMyLocation()` you call the `Geocoder.getFromLocation()` with hardcoded latitude and longitude. Is this for debugging purposes?
- Then there's a `System.println()` of a newly created , empty StringBuilder. If you want to print something out it's better to use `Log.d()`.
- And finally - if everything else works, but you still get no address in the textview - then try to `Toast` the address. It has less possibilities to go wrong but you need to stare on the screen as the message disappears after a second.

My guess here is, that your Emulator has no GPS configured or you do not get updates - either because there's no satellite or you simply do not wait long enough for satellite connections.